# Turning off wifi in Ubuntu 18.04 turns on aeroplane mode

Tags: wireless, 18.04, airplane-mode

Whenever I turn off wifi, aeroplane mode is turned on automatically .
Is this a bug in Ubuntu 18.04?

Output of `rfkill list` after wifi is turned off:

```
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
2: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
4: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: turn off wifi and then post the output of `rfkill list`.

Comment: @j-money posted the output.

Comment: an alternative could be to turn off wifi via terminal or script: `sudo ip link set wlan0 down` exchange wlan0 with your inteface name that you want to turn off. `sudo ip link set wlan0 up` will bring it up again. Btw. what manufacturer / laptop type are u using - just curious

Comment: @AlexOnLinux hp-15ab522tx

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/1767542

Answer (score 2):

'Aeroplane mode' just suspends radio-frequency signal transmission by the device, and thus disables Bluetooth and Wi-Fi.

*If* you already had Bluetooth disabled, turning off Wi-Fi disables *all* radio-frequency signal transmission devices of your system (presuming there are no other such device, e.g. telephony present). So Ubuntu notifies you of that fact by showing the aeroplane mode symbol. I don't see a problem there.

However, if Bluetooth *is* turned on and still turning off Wi-Fi triggers aeroplane mode and disables Bluetooth along the way, then it would be a bug.

Comment: Don't get it... I presumed you don't have any *other* radio-frequency signal transmitting devices like telephony as they're uncommon in a computing system, but then again I don't know what exactly your system consists of.

Comment: The button says "turn wifi off", also turns off bluetooth. Totally makes sense, right?

Comment: @Ufos That sound normal, consider asking a new question. Or if you think you have discovered a bug, then report at launchpad.net instead.

Comment: ^^ Somehow I missed a "*does not*" before "*sound normal*" above!

Answer (score 2):

It is considered a bug by Ubuntu. Here's a link: 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-control-center/+bug/1767542

---

*But it also could've been a deliberate UX decision.*